# More SSH Permission denied blues

Tags: networking, pi-zero-w, ubuntu

I have recently purchased the raspberry-pi Zero W and i must say it is nice little device accept for my little ssh issue every time i try to ssh all i get:

```
pi@raspberrypi's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
pi@raspberrypi's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
pi@raspberrypi's password: 
pi@raspberrypi: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

I have:

- added SSH file to /boot
- added `modules-load=dwc2,g_ether` after `rootwait`

I even accessed the pi in GUI mode and Enabled ssh in the preference and still access denied i also added firewall rules for port 22 still no avail I am running ubuntu20.

Comment: If your running ubuntu pi won't be the default user (or a user at all unless you setup a user called pi yourself). You have to setup your user on first boot with ubuntu. What username do you use to log when plugged into a monitor. To ssh in it should be username@ip

Comment: Look in /var/log/auth.log on the pi. There will likely be log messages indicating what the problem is.

Comment: Why did you choose Ubuntu? RaspiOS would be a much better choice for the novice users.

Comment: This question makes no sense. You can't run Ubuntu on a Pi Zero

Comment: While in GUI mode, set your password. Also, please note that on Ubuntu, the default user is probably named "ubuntu," so you should SSH to the Pi with "ssh ubuntu@the.ip.address" and the password that you chose.